# Cutting a line by a list of varied percentages along

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, analysis

Does anyone know a way to cut a line at specified percentages along that line? I know you can do this in ArcGIS if you have a specific percentage in mind, but I want to do it at varied percentages (5, 25, 26.5, 55.5, etc.). Hoas anyone figured out an easy way to do this? Can it be done in QGIS? ArcGIS?

Comment: It can be done with a python script by using 'interpolate' method of shapely or PyQGIS.

Comment: Linear referencing designed for exactly this

Comment: Please decide which of ArcGIS Desktop and QGIS you wish to ask about in this particular question.  Also, if you decide to ask about ArcPy or PyQGIS, then you will need to include a code snippet.